# pressing keys in visual line mode will leave this mode?

Tags: key-bindings, visual-mode

I find that in visual line mode, if I press a shortcut to print the current mode, it will print `n` instead of `V`. Is this the expected behavior?

My mapping:

```
xnoremap <a-j> :<c-u>echo mode()<CR>
```

Then select some lines of text, and press `<a-j>`, it will print `n` (normal mode) instead of `V` (visual line).

Comment: Once you’ve entered your command, you drop back to normal mode. So I’m inclined to think that’s intentional, since you’re no longer in Visual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, pressing **some keys** in Vim could switch the current mode. Still surprised?

This is documented under `:h mode-switching`. Obviously, here you have even two transitions: one by colon, and another one by enter key.

But, I admit, it's confusing on the first encounter. In Neovim they even invented `:h <Cmd>` to deal with this. But in plain Vim you have only `:h map-<expr>` to stay Visual, while executing script.

However, the main point is that you rarely need to stay Visual for real. Just read the bookmarks (`:h '<` and `:h '>`) and move on. Do `:h gv` when needed to enter Visual mode again.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations! I guess I can then use `'<` and `'>` to get the previously-selected lines inside a function, which are called from the maping.